# How to identify the varname from an OLS fit summary?

Tags: python, linear-regression, summary, variable-names

This is a model for MLB, and to my understanding each var name (x1,x2,x3...) should be associated with a pitcher name. How can I identify which pitcher is associated with the var name?

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:      successful_at_bat   R-squared:                       0.055
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.045
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     5.207
Date:                Tue, 01 Jun 2021   Prob (F-statistic):               0.00
Time:                        18:57:55   Log-Likelihood:                -42135.
No. Observations:               65866   AIC:                         8.574e+04
Df Residuals:                   65131   BIC:                         9.243e+04
Df Model:                         734                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust     
       coef  std err       t  P>|t|  [0.025  0.975]
x1   0.9994    0.020  50.594  0.000   0.961   1.038
x2   0.2606    0.139   1.871  0.061  -0.012   0.534
x3   0.2035    0.109   1.869  0.062  -0.010   0.417
x4  -0.0138    0.061  -0.224  0.822  -0.134   0.107
x5  -0.0558    0.112  -0.498  0.618  -0.276   0.164
x6   0.0275    0.073   0.375  0.708  -0.116   0.171
x7   0.0896    0.206   0.434  0.664  -0.315   0.494
x8   0.0071    0.043   0.164  0.870  -0.078   0.092
x9  -0.0242    0.049  -0.498  0.618  -0.119   0.071
x10 -0.0366    0.036  -1.028  0.304  -0.107   0.033
```

Code used:

```py
dummy_df = pd.get_dummies(at_bat_data['pitcher_name']).reset_index(drop=True) 
complete_at_bat_level_data_dummy = pd.concat([at_bat_data.reset_index(drop=True),dummy_df], axis=1) 
covariate_df = pd.merge(complete_at_bat_level_data_dummy, complete_pitch_level_data , on=['batter_name','game_date']) 
y = covariate_df['successful_at_bat'] 
x = covariate_df[['batting_average_homeMade'] + list(dummy_df.columns)].values 
model = sm.OLS(y,x) 
fit = model.fit() 
fit_summary = fit.summary()
```

Comment: In order to identify which pitcher is associated with each variable of `x` you would have to use the metadata of the inputdata i.e. some data describing which pitcher was x1 or x2. The OLS model provides different data for eg the coef is the impact of that variable x on the dep variable successful_at_bat when considering the other players or x variables.

Comment: I've edited your question to include the code you just shared so that other S/O users may also respond